# How to search customer type records alone in Netsuite Suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I can search customer records using below script. This was working fine.

```
require(['N/search'])
search = require('N/search')
var options = {
    type: "customer"
};
options.columns = ["companyname", "firstname", "middlename", "lastname"];

var customerSearch = search.create(options);

var results = customerSearch.run({
}).getRange({
    start: 0,
    end: 5
});

log.debug(results)
```

I get result as list of customer, lead, prospect & job.

Why I get lead, prospect & job records while searching customer?

How to get customer type records alone while searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this because all of those are 'stages' of the customer process.

You need to add a filter:

```
options.filters = [['stage', 'anyof', ['CUSTOMER']]];
```

Comment: Thank you. Can I use "options.filters = ['stage', search.Operator.IS, 'CUSTOMER'];"?
is there any performance difference from yours and the above one?

Comment: I think you can use either form. I've sometimes run into problems using 'is' operators on enumerable values like that so I tend to stick with the form I wrote. Note the issues may have been long since fixed. I'm coming up on 20 years of Netsuite. I doubt there is any permformance difference. When I've checked calls like that in the console Netsuite generally converts to the 'anyof' form